# Where did Falcon's pistols go?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, the-falcon-and-the-winter-soldier

In the movies, Falcon has a pair of machine pistols that he uses to good effect in combination with his flight suit, making for a rather unique fighting style.  But in *The Falcon and the Winter Soldier*, his pistols are conspicuous in their absence, and their absence drops his effectiveness in a fight waaaaaaay down, leaving him kind of crippled for most of this action-heavy series.

There are plenty of points where they would have made a big difference.  Probably the most notable is in the final episode, a whole lot of grief and struggle could have been headed off if he had just shot Batroc instead of rehashing a fight sequence that we basically already saw in *Captain America: The Winter Soldier* anyway.

Do we have any canonical explanation for what happened to his pistols during these events?  Or were they simply confiscated by the writers or the director in order to cripple him, thereby enhancing drama?

Comment: Shooting to kill people isn’t very Captain America-y. He’s moved passed just being a soldier on a similar arc to Steve.

Comment: I agree with @TheLethalCarrot, it's a transition to a more defensive fighting style which is a fitting projection of the highly moral Captain America.

Comment: @EleventhDoctor Just to be clear, we are talking about [this highly moral guy,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jQbb43yLfO0) right?  People who say that a moral superhero never kills bad guys do not understand heroes *or* morality.

Comment: Captain America operates with a [minimum of necessary force](https://screenrant.com/falcon-winter-soldier-steve-rogers-captain-america-killed/) for moral, ethical and symbolic reasons. Yes,  I've seen the movies too and he _does_ kill people.

Answer (score 1):

This was addressed by the show's director Kari Skogland. The decision was consciously taken to dial down the use of guns, ostensibly to make the show 'smarter' for audiences and less reliant on gunplay.

> **KS:** ... *I guess one of the things that I did as a sort of overview was that we reduced weaponry. That does mean that all the things we choreographed come from sort of a different mindset, and that just by definition brings a different flavor to a scene.*
>
> **AVC:** **Why did you decide to do that?**
>
> **KS:** *For obvious reasons. I think that we need to look at weaponry in entertainment as being too much of a crutch. We wanted to have our characters be clever and interesting and not just rely on the go-to.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Marvel Director Wanted Less Guns In Falcon and the Winter Soldier](https://www.avclub.com/the-falcon-and-the-winter-soldier-consciously-dialed-ba-1846515439)</sup></sub>

It's worthwhile noting that the show was broadcast primarily on Disney+, so the audience would be younger than would normally be expected for a tentpole MCU film.

Comment: Also for budgetary reasons he's mostly fighting powered humans rather than CGI monsters, so they can't be shown getting shot without having to explore the consequences.